# getting a "Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet" when starting springboot project from intellij

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, intellij-14, maven-tomcat-plugin

I created a simple springboot project from Spring Initializr.
when starting springboot project from intellij, I am getting below exception but when running from terminal using maven I don't get any exception(mvn spring-boot:run).I tried solving this by adding below to my pom.xml, but after I was getting some other exceptions and solve that I get some more exception. Please tell anyone of you were able to solve this.

Thank you

```
 .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.2.5.RELEASE)
2015-07-18 12:08:55.180  INFO 5387 --- [           main] connect2x.Connect2xApplication           : Starting Connect2xApplication on Karthiks-MBP.attlocal.net with PID 5387 (/Users/sravanikarthik/Desktop/connect2x/target/classes started by sravanikarthik in /Users/sravanikarthik/Desktop/connect2x)
2015-07-18 12:08:55.479  INFO 5387 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@289d1c02: startup date [Sat Jul 18 12:08:55 CDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-07-18 12:08:57.746  INFO 5387 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/packager.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar, file:/Users/sravanikarthik/Desktop/connect2x/target/classes/, file:/Users/sravanikarthik/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-actuator-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sravanikarthik/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sravanikarthik/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sravanikarthik/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sravanikarthik/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sravanikarthik/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.12/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar, file:/Users/sravanikarthik/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.12/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.12.jar, file:/Users/sravanikarthik/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.12/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar, file:/Users/sravanikarthik/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.3/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar, file:/Users/sravanikarthik/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.3/logback-core-1.1.3.jar, file:/Users/sravanikarthik/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.14/snakeyaml-1.14.jar, file:/Users/sravanikarthik/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-actuator/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-actuator-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sravanikarthik/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.4.6/jackson-databind-2.4.6.jar, file:/Users/sravanikarthik/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.4.6/jackson-annotations-2.4.6.jar, file:/Users/sravanikarthik/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.4.6/jackson-core-2.4.6.jar, file:/Users/sravanikarthik/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sravanikarthik/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sravanikarthik/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/Users/sravanikarthik/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sravanikarthik/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sravanikarthik/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sravanikarthik/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin-spring-boot-starter/1.0.0.beta3/vaadin-spring-boot-starter-1.0.0.beta3.jar, file:/Users/sravanikarthik/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin-spring-boot/1.0.0.beta3/vaadin-spring-boot-1.0.0.beta3.jar, file:/Users/sravanikarthik/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin-spring/1.0.0.beta3/vaadin-spring-1.0.0.beta3.jar, file:/Users/sravanikarthik/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin-server/7.4.5/vaadin-server-7.4.5.jar, file:/Users/sravanikarthik/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin-sass-compiler/0.9.12/vaadin-sass-compiler-0.9.12.jar, file:/Users/sravanikarthik/.m2/repository/org/w3c/css/sac/1.3/sac-1.3.jar, file:/Users/sravanikarthik/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/external/flute/flute/1.3.0.gg2/flute-1.3.0.gg2.jar, file:/Users/sravanikarthik/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin-shared/7.4.5/vaadin-shared-7.4.5.jar, file:/Users/sravanikarthik/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/external/streamhtmlparser/streamhtmlparser-jsilver/0.0.10.vaadin1/streamhtmlparser-jsilver-0.0.10.vaadin1.jar, file:/Users/sravanikarthik/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/external/google/guava/16.0.1.vaadin1/guava-16.0.1.vaadin1.jar, file:/Users/sravanikarthik/.m2/repository/org/jsoup/jsoup/1.8.1/jsoup-1.8.1.jar, file:/Users/sravanikarthik/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.12/slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar, file:/Users/sravanikarthik/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sravanikarthik/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sravanikarthik/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.1.3.Final/hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar, file:/Users/sravanikarthik/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/Users/sravanikarthik/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.1.3.GA/jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar, file:/Users/sravanikarthik/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.0.0/classmate-1.0.0.jar, file:/Users/sravanikarthik/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/sravanikarthik/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin-themes/7.4.5/vaadin-themes-7.4.5.jar, file:/Users/sravanikarthik/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin-client-compiled/7.4.5/vaadin-client-compiled-7.4.5.jar, file:/Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA%2014.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar]
2015-07-18 12:08:57.815 ERROR 5387 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.AuditAutoConfiguration$AuditEventRepositoryConfiguration due to internal class not found. This can happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:51)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:102)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader$TrackedConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:452)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:135)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:124)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:318)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at connect2x.Connect2xApplication.main(Connect2xApplication.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:572)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:489)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:475)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:535)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:677)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:621)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:591)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1397)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:968)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry$OptimizedBeanTypeRegistry.addBeanTypeForNonAliasDefinition(BeanTypeRegistry.java:271)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry$OptimizedBeanTypeRegistry.addBeanType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:260)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry$OptimizedBeanTypeRegistry.getNamesForType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:241)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:163)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:152)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:95)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:45)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 52 common frames omitted

2015-07-18 12:08:57.816  INFO 5387 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@289d1c02: startup date [Sat Jul 18 12:08:55 CDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.AuditAutoConfiguration$AuditEventRepositoryConfiguration due to internal class not found. This can happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)
2015-07-18 12:08:57.842 at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:51)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:102)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader$TrackedConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:452)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:135)
 WARN   at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:124)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:318)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239)
5387    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
--- at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
[           main]   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at connect2x.Connect2xApplication.main(Connect2xApplication.java:10)
:   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@289d1c02: startup date [Sat Jul 18 12:08:55 CDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:344)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:331)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:836)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:342)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at connect2x.Connect2xApplication.main(Connect2xApplication.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)

    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
2015-07-18 12:08:57.843 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 WARN   at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
5387    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:572)
--- at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:489)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:475)
 [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close

java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@289d1c02: startup date [Sat Jul 18 12:08:55 CDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:535)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:357)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:677)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:621)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:836)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:591)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:342)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:968)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry$OptimizedBeanTypeRegistry.addBeanTypeForNonAliasDefinition(BeanTypeRegistry.java:271)
    at connect2x.Connect2xApplication.main(Connect2xApplication.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry$OptimizedBeanTypeRegistry.addBeanType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:260)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry$OptimizedBeanTypeRegistry.getNamesForType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:241)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:163)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:152)

    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:95)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:45)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 52 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Springboot project runs fine when running from terminal using command mvn spring-boot:run

Running from Intellij is when I was getting an exception. I changed the spring-boot-starter-tomcat in pom.xml to an older version and it runs without any exception. I think the issue was with compatibly for latest maven embed tomcat 1.2.5.RELEASE.

Now I am using below in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 5):

I am using below in my pom.xml,nonuse provided

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is missing tomcat jars because of dependency scope is provided.

[Dependency Scope](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope)

> provided : This is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK
>   or a container to provide the dependency at runtime.
>
> compile : This is the default scope, used if none is specified. Compile
>   dependencies are available in all classpaths of a project.
>   Furthermore, those dependencies are propagated to dependent projects.

If you will use embedded tomcat to run `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` and `tomcat-embed-jasper` these artifacts dependency scope should be compile which is default. Just use them like below.

```
        <!-- Need this to compile JSP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>

         <!-- Tomcat embedded container-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

After `mvn clean install` and `mvn package` try to run your project inside Idea.

For traditional deployment approach(deploy boot project to external tomcat) please check below links to not have problem in deployment step.

[How to Traditional Deployment](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-traditional-deployment)

Answer (score 0):

Add your Server Library in the class-path of the your project.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, it looks like you don't have your classes in packages. For component scan and auto configuration to work you need to have packages. Try moving you classes out of default and into packages with you main class at the root of your package. The main must be at the root because component scan only scans in and down the package hierarchy not up.