# Springboot 1.4.2 Release - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class:

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am running a maven project. When I try to use IntelliJ and run application.java, I am getting errors. When I try to do a maven install, it is building the war file and using java -jar I am able to successfully run and view my website at http://localhost.

Also, when I open the project using Eclipse IDE and run Application.java, it is working fine. I am not sure what I am missing when I am using IntelliJ (version Ultimate 2017.3)

Below is the error I am getting

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.2.RELEASE)

2018-04-13 22:38:02.910  INFO 27544 --- [           main] brewPkg.Application                      : Starting Application on 44629UCHIPPAD-7 with PID 27544 (C:\Users\uchippad\PCDNG\brew-uds\target\classes started by uchippad in C:\Users\uchippad\PCDNG\brew-uds)
2018-04-13 22:38:02.920  INFO 27544 --- [           main] brewPkg.Application                      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-04-13 22:38:03.030  INFO 27544 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@477b4cdf: startup date [Fri Apr 13 22:38:03 EDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-04-13 22:38:04.899 ERROR 27544 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: brewPkg.BrewController
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:419) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:266) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:281) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:125) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:686) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:524) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at brewPkg.Application.main(Application.java:34) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:79) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:116) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:291) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:480) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:337) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.createClass(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:135) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:107) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:409) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.addAllMethods(ReflectUtils.java:372) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.getMethods(Enhancer.java:540) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:575) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.transform.TransformingClassGenerator.generateClass(TransformingClassGenerator.java:33) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanFactoryAwareGeneratorStrategy.generate(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:249) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:329) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generate(Enhancer.java:492) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:93) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:91) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    ... 35 common frames omitted

2018-04-13 22:38:04.907  INFO 27544 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@477b4cdf: startup date [Fri Apr 13 22:38:03 EDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-04-13 22:38:04.912  WARN 27544 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close

java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@477b4cdf: startup date [Fri Apr 13 22:38:03 EDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:417) [spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1002) [spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:961) [spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:818) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at brewPkg.Application.main(Application.java:34) [classes/:na]

2018-04-13 22:38:04.914 ERROR 27544 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Destroy method on bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory' threw an exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@477b4cdf: startup date [Fri Apr 13 22:38:03 EDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404) [spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:97) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:253) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578) [spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554) [spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:954) [spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523) [spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) [spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1033) [spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1009) [spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:961) [spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:818) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at brewPkg.Application.main(Application.java:34) [classes/:na]


Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.companyname.brew</groupId>
    <artifactId>brew-uds</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <version>1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>project.local</id>
            <name>project</name>
            <url>file:${project.basedir}/repo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Web with Tomcat + Embed -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>           
        </dependency>

        <!-- Need this to compile JSP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>         
        </dependency>

        <!-- Need this to compile JSP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
            <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>         
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache POI Exporting to Excel, Word, etc.-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Optional, for bootstrap -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7</version>            
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160810</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.nzjdbc-7</groupId>
            <artifactId>nzjdbc-7.0.2</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jgit/org.eclipse.jgit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jgit</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.jgit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.0.201706111038-r</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jcraft/jsch -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.54</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This is the Application.java

```
// This is the main class. It's responsible for starting the spring application

package brewPkg;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;


import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application{
    private static HttpServletResponse response;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    //  DEFAULT
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    }

}
```

I am using jdk1.8.0_60

Thanks.

Comment: Did you import it as a Maven project?

Comment: yes imported it as maven project .. i have apache-maven-3.5.2 installed in my computer

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31494183/getting-a-caused-by-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-servlet-http-httpser?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa?

Comment: Thanks @JamieBisotti that was exactly the answer I was looking for .. that helped .. i removed <scope>provided</scope> on all my tomcat dependencies and do not get the error now

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error while using Spring Tool Suite 4. I found that the installed JRE location wasn't the same to the default Java path, changing the default JRE location in the `Installed JREs` tab worked for me. You can go to
`Preferences` > `Java` > `Installed JREs` to add the right Java path and check it.

Answer (score 1):

same issue happened to me fixed by changing the spring framework version in pom.xml

from  2.0.3.RELEASE

```
   <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>  
</parent>
```

to  2.6.2

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.2</version>
</parent>
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue can occur if you use a major version to compile in your pom.xml file.

[image]

Make sure that your java run time environment and compile time environments are same.
You can check this by using `java -version` and `javac -version` cmd commands.