# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class : com.project.config

Tags: java, spring

I have a spring core application. In which I have private constructors. while executing the application, it throws

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class
```

at the time of bean creation.

I searched over I found that, could be problem because of AOP, but I am not using AOP. What would be the problem.

```
    private Demo() {
         //private constructor.
     }
```

Comment: Share the code that would result in the exception

Comment: Possible duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49827402/4214241) which is a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31494183/4214241).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make a public constructor in order spring framework can instantiate the bean, the other way  you can do it is doing a public static factory method, but you will need to say to the spring framework, what uses this method in order to instantiate this bean.